username not being applied with filter freeradius ldap
The username is not being used for the ldap search.
Ready to process requests
(0) Received Access-Request Id 46 from 10.200.2.189:49933 to 10.200.2.88:1812 length 46
(0)   User-Name = "test"
(0)   User-Password = "test"
(0) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
(0)   authorize {
(0)     [preprocess] = ok
(0)     [chap] = noop
(0)     [mschap] = noop
(0) suffix: Checking for suffix after "@"
(0) suffix: No '@' in User-Name = "test", looking up realm NULL
(0) suffix: No such realm "NULL"
(0)     [suffix] = noop
(0) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(0)     [eap] = noop
rlm_ldap (ldap): Reserved connection (0)
(0) ldap: Performing search in "OU=test,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=com" with filter "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%{User-Name}))", scope "sub"

I already tried a lot of differetent filters, I cant figure it out.

In the configured query filter, try changing %{User-Name} to %{&User-Name}

Thansk @MathiasR.Jessen for your comment.
This unfortunately still gives the following:
(0) ldap: Performing search in "OU=test,DC=ad,DC=test,DC=com" with filter "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%{&User-Name})
The username should show as User-Name right? That's why the ldap filter is not finding anything.
It again does show that
(0)   User-Name = "test"
(0)   User-Password = "test"
Any other idea's why this is occuring?
Thanks for the help!

It's been a while since I used freeradius, but the log message should have the filter after templating, so yeah, I would expect the log message to say "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=test)". Can you share the configuration file? Or at least the ldap section (redact any secrets)

@MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for your time to try and help me. I will send my current ldap file in mods available. I tried to already use a group so that only devices added to the group may connect.
https://pastebin.com/vYsenvu9
